# Stop Intellij / Android Studio Preview adding newlines when formatting anonymous inner class parameters

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm trying to stop Android Studio Preview (ie IntelliJ) from adding in a newline / carriage return after an anonymous inner class when it's defined as a method parameter. It changes this:

```java
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Some code
    }
});
```

to this:

```java
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Some code
    }
}
);
```

I've looked through the formatting settings, but can't seem to find the relevant setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out these options:

[image]

Let me know if it doesn't work for you